# When using v-for, why does the key prop value not propagate to the child component?

Tags: vuejs2

Why is the `key` prop's value empty in the child component?

Vue code:

```
Vue.component('my-column',{
    props: ['items'],
    template: `
  <div>
    <my-row
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :item="item"
      :index="index"
      :key="item.id"
    ></my-row>
  </div>
  `,
})
Vue.component('my-row',{
    props: ['item', 'index', 'key'],
    template: `
     <div class="item--row">
       <p>{{ item.name }} {{ item.id }} - {{ key }}</p>
     </div>
  `
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function () {
    return {
      items: [
        { id: 0, name: 'one' },
        { id: 1, name: 'two' },
        { id: 2, name: 'three' },
      ]
    }
  },
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <my-column items="items"></my-column>
</div>
```

Output is:

```
one 0 -
two 1 -
three 2 -
```

Expected output:

```
one 0 - 0
two 1 - 1
three 2 - 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because key is already an registered [vue attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key). You have to rename key to something else in order to use it as a prop. `key` attribute is meant to be used to tell Vue to track elements for it's optimization.

If you do not provide a key, Vue will try its best to reuse code that looks similar. This might sometimes not be what you want. This is why the `key` was introduced I believe.